# Determining communication range based on the transmission power

Tags: omnet++

I have to determining the minimum communication range based on the transmission power to send a ping message from an host to another one wirelessly through a simple wall in OMNeT++.

I'm using the DielectricObstacleLoss model.

My .ini file is:

```
[Config Network]
network = Network

# application parameters
*.source.numPingApps = 1
*.source.pingApp[0].destAddr = "destination"

*.source.wlan[0].radio.displayCommunicationRange = true

# radio medium parameters
*.radioMedium.obstacleLossType = "DielectricObstacleLoss"
```

I read the INET manual at the link: https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/inet-manual-draft.pdf and in the Path Loss Models section (page 45) is written that computing the traveled distance based on the power loss factor, the signal frequency and the propagation speed is useful for determining the maximum communication range based on the transmission power.

However, I haven't seen anything about trasmitter power in FreeSpacePathLoss.cc and TwoRayGroundReflection.cc codes.

So, can I use the FreeSpacePathLoss or TwoRayGroundReflection models to solve my problem, or there is another solution ?